# double inverted commas in css

Tags: html, css

I have a design which I am trying to replicate in HTML and CSS.

[image]

At this moment, I am able to get this in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ch1dbygs/2/show/) but I am unable to replicate double inverted commas as shown in the design.

The HTML code which I am using for the second paragraph is:

```
<div id="line2" class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="cofounder-ceo-image">
                        <img src="assets/img/Uploads/jack_v1.jpg"> </div>
                    <p>Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say </p>

                    <p class="ceo">Jack Lau - Co-founder and CEO</p>
                </div>
```

I am wondering, Is there any way I can replicate double inverted commas in CSS or just we need to post an image of double inverted commas at specific location ?

Comment: So you decided to go with floats, even though you are using a grid system? Floats are really not recommended for this type of layout anymore.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I am considering your solution as well :)

Comment: I just know the trouble that working with floats can cause - using a robust grid system like Bootstrap makes it 20 times easier - there's a good reason its so widely used! Learn from all my bad experiences with floats, clearfix and messed-up layouts :) And with regard to your question - both answers below are correct so you should accept one to make the question resolved. They only thing they haven't done is identify the font for the double quotes... which isn't really something you could expect anyone to know offhand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `::after` pseudoelement. After every paragraph, add the inverted quotes and position them to the required side. This code is only for the first paragraph (only at the right), but you can easily make a repeatable class, one for each side, just switching `right` and `left` properties accordingly. Something like this:

```
#line2 p {
  position: relative;
}
#line2 p:after {
  content: "\"";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: -100px;
  font-size: 140px;
  color: gray;
}
```

If you need that exact "inverted comma", use the exact same font as your example, or simply an image:

```
#line2 p:after {
  content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyH2G.png);
  position: absolute;
  top: -70px;
  right: -100px;
  font-size: 140px;
  color: gray;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofmmudxv/)

Comment: Its not the same shape. Although I can see inverted commas there but shape is little bit different there.

Comment: Where did you get those commas from? It looks like it's just a typography. Why not use `font-family` on the pseudoelement, so you can have exactly that shape?

Comment: Check the updated fiddle. I just took a screenshot of the comma you want, maybe you can approach it like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use psedoelements (`::after` and `::before`) to kind of attach an element to another element like this:

```
.our-vision p{
  position: relative;
}

.our-vision #line2 > p::before,
.our-vision #line3 > p::after{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #ccc;
}

.our-vision #line2 > p::before{  
  content:"\201D";
  top: -0.5em;
  right: -0.5em;
}

.our-vision #line3 > p::after{
  content:"\201C";
  bottom: -0.5em;
  left: -0.5em;
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ttfwchq3/3/

However, what you're designing here seems like a [blockquote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote) (although in reverse direction). If that's the case, you might want to style a blockquote element and use it like that.

Comment: Its not the same shape. Although I can see inverted commas there but shape is little bit different there.

Comment: Checked. Still, I can spot some differences :).

Comment: If you're looking for the **EXACT** same image, you should use the same font. `our-vision #line2 > p::before,
.our-vision #line3 > p::after{ font-family: "Calibri"; ....` for instance changes it a lot. I really don't know which font it's using but you could find it with some trial and error maybe

Comment: If you can't, you can always use an image instead of the Unicode character. Just use an empty `content` and set the background image.